# Angular 2 Root module merge

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I created a multi App application with several root ngModule's that works perfectly as separate apps.
I'm using Angular 4 with ng-cli.
Now I want to achieve the same but i'm thiking in a way to merge the root ngModules of each app into one to launch all the separated apps integrated.

Any clues on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look to angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#feature-modules

Feature modules and lazy loading I think is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have modules: A, B, and C.  Now you would probably want to make a new module called AppModule which then imports A, B, and C like so:

```
  @NgModule({
  ... (all the other stuff that normally goes into ng module)
  imports: [
    A,
    B,
    C
  ] }
```

You will now need to figure out your routing structure.  You said that you had multiple stand alone applications.  In that scenario they might have all live on different domains but if you combine them into one mega application then you'll be better off to have them live from the same domain.

So you'll need a url structure like app.com/A, app.com/B, and app.com/C for the different apps.